# What are the UIManager keys for JFileChooser and FileDialog?

Tags: java, swing, awt, look-and-feel, uimanager

I want to use the UIManager.get method in order to get and save the system look and feel for JFileChooser and FileDialog and then I want to change the look and feel.

The problem is that I don't know what are the keys for Swing components that UIManager.get method uses. Is there any reference or any convention for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/)

Comment: this talks about component properties, I want the whole component.