# How can we merge elements from different look and feels?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel

I am a beginner in Java GUI, and I want to set a good looking look and feel; but the problem is that I don't like any of the look and feel completely. Everyone has some good and some bad styles. Being specific, I am using Nimbus look and feel, but I like the table and text area of liquid look and feel. I want to use Nimbus look and feel as default, but only use `JTable` and `JTextArea` of Liquid Look and feel. Is this possible?

Please answer using easy vocabulary, as I said I am a beginner.

ps: I use Netbeans.

Comment: I am using netbeans as an IDE, This is just for your information.

Comment: I can't really be done, not without a lot of work.  A look and feel is expected to be a single, unified presentation layer.  You could take a look at [Synth Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html) which is about skinning and which Nimbus uses.  Personally, I'd stick to the platform look and feel, you'll get much more user acceptance if you stick to what the user expects and is use to - IMHO

Comment: Thanks for your help, is it your opinion or you are sure about it? that It Can't be done

Comment: @MadProgrammer's caveats are well founded; only you can determine if the _ad hoc_ approach I suggest below will meet your requirements for user acceptance.

Comment: The Problem is that I don't want to set the icons but I need to change the whole look and feel of a Swing Component for example in seaGlass

Comment: The JtextArea shows very good fonts as well as lines which I like and i want to override the Nimbus TextArea with the Sea Glass Look And Feel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use the *ad hoc* approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14262706/230513) for `JTree` icons.

[image]

Left: `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`

Right: `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel`

Addendum: While not all combinations are compatible, you can examine the defined [UIManager Defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3974748/230513) for keys common to both. A few `JTable` examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:230513%20%5Bjtable%5D%20uimanager).

Comment: sorry, but the problem is that I said in my question that I want to use only Jtable and JtextArea, I have already used the renderer for Jtree. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) based on the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14262706/230513) cited and the relevant [`UIManager` defaults](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3974748/230513).

Comment: what is the need of SSCCE when, Netbeans automatically sets the Nimbus Look & Feel code in main Method

Comment: You'd need to do so if you have specific trouble with this approach.

Comment: are you saying this that the ad hoc approach can even be used on any look and feel

Comment: Yes, but @MadProgrammer is also correct that not all combinations are fruitful. You'll have to test empirically.

Comment: I was trying to ask that will the ad hoc approach will be applicable on JtextArea and JTable or it can only be used in JTree

Comment: What `UIManager` keys did you try? What happened when you tried them?

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to say, I am just using Netbeans as an IDE and in that I am using it's Drag and Drop Tool with Free Design Layout

Comment: I just can't find your answer valid because I also knew completely how to render a JTree and I did it before but I cannot render Jtable and JtextArea

Comment: These [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+%5Bjtable%5D+uimanager) illustrate changing various `UIManager` properties used by `JTable`; experiment with changing them.